# 辞書を任意的に並び替えして出力させたい

Tags: python

以下がdict1という辞書に対して行いたい処理です。

dict1のkey[0]からアルファベット順に並べ、同じアルファベットの中でもkey[1]から数字が小さい順に並べて、さらにkey[2],key[3]でも同様に分類して出力させたいです。

知識不足ながらプログラム案を考えてみましたが、上手くできません。ご教示お願い致します。

**対象の辞書データ:**

```
dict1 = {
    ('a', '1', 'a', '2'): ['A'],
    ('a', '1', 'a', '1'): ['B', 'C'],
    ('b', '1', 'a', '2'): ['D'],
    ('c', '1', 'a', '3'): ['E'],
    ('b', '1', 'b', '3'): ['F'],
    ('c', '1', 'd', '3'): ['G'],
    ('a', '2', 'd', '2'): ['H']
}
```

**期待する結果:**

```
result =

　　　a 1
  　　　a 1  B,C
  　　　a 2  A 
　　　a 2
  　　　d 2  H
　　　b 1
  　　　a 2  D
  　　　b 3  F
　　　c 1
  　　　a 3  E
  　　　d 3  G
```

**現状のコードと出力結果:**

```
for c,p in dict1.items():
  print(*c,*p)

# 出力
a 1 a 2 A
a 1 a 1 B C
b 1 a 2 D
c 1 a 3 E
b 1 b 3 F
c 1 d 3 G
a 2 d 2 H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from itertools import groupby

dict1 = {
    ('a', '1', 'a', '2'): ['A'],
    ('a', '1', 'a', '1'): ['B', 'C'],
    ('b', '1', 'a', '2'): ['D'],
    ('c', '1', 'a', '3'): ['E'],
    ('b', '1', 'b', '3'): ['F'],
    ('c', '1', 'd', '3'): ['G'],
    ('a', '2', 'd', '2'): ['H'],
}

keyf = lambda x: x[:2]
for k, g in groupby(sorted(dict1, key=keyf), key=keyf):
    print(*k)
    for v in sorted(g, key=lambda x: x[2:]):
        print(' ', *v[2:], '', ','.join(dict1[v]))

# a 1
#   a 1  B,C
#   a 2  A
# a 2
#   d 2  H
# b 1
#   a 2  D
#   b 3  F
# c 1
#   a 3  E
#   d 3  G
```